# Is any other code can write in Functional way in Angular?

Tags: angular

As I know, there are some type of the Angular v17 code can be written in Functional way:

1. Functional HTTP Interceptors
2. Functional Route Guards
3. Functional Validator (Reactive forms)

I'm curious that are there any other types of code can be written in Functional way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it sumed up correctly, those are the 3 major features where you can use functionnal APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know why someone downvote your answer and my question. 